# How can I display a larger image when clicking on a thumbnail for an image field?

Tags: 9, media

Many of the answers are related to Drupal 7, but I'm asking for Drupal 8/9. I have an image field and currently display it as a 100x100 thumbnail. I want to link it to a larger image or make it into a slideshow. From the display layout, I am able to select content, but it goes to the page itself. And if I select media, it tries to goto the media/edit page of that image. How can I link it to a larger version of the image or make it into a slideshow?

Comment: This mechanism is often called Lightbox. Look for a Lightbox library that fits your needs, get it into your project and adjust the markup accordingly. Or try any of the existing Lightbox contrib modules. They often come with a field formatter you then can simply select for your image field.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) contrib module.

Here is a [good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqM80QHK_8E&ab_channel=SamuliNatri) of it.